# LibGdx: set TextButton font to a TrueTypeFont

Tags: android, libgdx, fonts, scale

I am making my first LibGdx game, and having an hard time understanding font scaling on TextButtons.

Here is a comparison between the rendering on my Kindle Fire 7 and an high resolution tablet:

[image]

I tried using the scale() method, but the result is a pixelated mess.

I've read about TrueType fonts, and I'd like to set the font size by calculating the screen density.

I've tried to create a TextButtonStyle containing a font with the following:

```
//Generate the font
FreeTypeFontGenerator generator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.internal("fonts/Merriweather-Regular.ttf"));
TextButtonStyle style = new TextButtonStyle();
FreeTypeFontParameter param = new FreeTypeFontParameter();

//Set the font size (12 as an example)
param.size = 12;
style.font = generator.generateFont(param);

//Set the new style to the button
button = new TextButton("START GAME", style);
```

The TextButton correctly gets the new font, BUT loses the actual button as only the text gets rendered; I guess that's because the new TextButtonStyle only contains information about the font and is otherwise empty.

I tried setting the new font to a Skin also, but only ended with further confusion; most resources I found online don't mention font rendering on TextButtons, or end up being confusing with convulted methods.

Is there a simple way to achieve what I want? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In my answer to [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39174630) I describe how you can add a TTF font to your `skin` file which will allow you to use the font on your labels.

Basically when you create your skin file you have to add an `ObjectMap` with the fonts inside and supply it to your skin's parameters.